# Jquery full calender just date is selectable

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have implemented the jquery full calendar. I have retrived  more events from database using Json. I want just date only selectable..ones i click date means displayed the all events..

Thanks,
world

Answer (score 0):

use the dayCkick function which is Triggered when the user clicks on a day.

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {}
```

inside it you can use the eventRender function to render all the events on happening on that particular day..

Do go through the documentation given to check out all the possibilities.
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/